# Compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ and complex curves

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-manifolds

I know that one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ gives us Reimann sphere. Also, Riemann sphere is homeomorphic to complex projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}) = S^{3}/{\sim}$ where $x \sim \lambda x$ for $|\lambda| = 1$.

Now consider the following way of compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ to get Riemann sphere:

> As a set we take the quotient $q \colon \mathbb{C} \amalg \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ of the disjoint union $\mathbb{C} \amalg \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C} \times \{0,1\}$ by the equivalence relation $\sim$ given by: $(z,i) \sim (w,j)$ if and only if (($i = j$ and $z = w$) or $(i \neq j$ and $zw = 1$)).
>   For $z \neq 0$ the element $(z,1)$ is equivalent to $(1/z, 0)$.
>   The set $\mathbb{C} \times \{0\} \amalg \{(0,1)\}$ is a set of representatives for $\sim$, and so $q$ is a bijection from that set to $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$.
>   Hence we can write $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C} \amalg \{\infty\}$.
>
> We give $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ the quotient topology:
>   for $U$ a subset of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ we let $U$ be open if and only if $q^{-1} U \subset \mathbb{C} \amalg \mathbb{C}$ is open.
>   Here $\mathbb{C} \amalg \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C} \times \{0,1\}$ has the product topology, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.
>
> We also have a notion of holomorphic functons.
>   Later we will describe “regular” functions on “open” subsets of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ for a topology to be defined.
>   On $\mathbb{C}$ these regular functions will just be the polynomial ones.
>
> A nice visualisation of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is as follows.
>   We define $D_0 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$ in the first chart $\mathbb{C} \times \{0\}$, and $D_{\infty} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$ in the second chart $\mathbb{C} \times \{1\}$.
>   Then the quotient map $q$ glues these two discs along their boundaries via the map $z \mapsto z^{-1}$.
>   As a topological space $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to the two-dimensional sphere $S^2$.
>   See Wikipedia (Riemann sphere) for more information.
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1v0U.png)

I don't understand this new method of compactification of $\mathbb{C}$.

Then a similar method is used to find the compactification of the curve
$$
  C = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : b^n = a^{n-1} - 1\}
$$
to get $\overline{C} = (C \amalg C')/{\sim}$ where
$$
 C' = \{(c,d) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : d^n = c - c^n\}
$$
and $(a,b) \sim (a^{-1}, ba^{-1})$ as follows:

> $$
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> \overline{C}
> @.
> :=
> @.
> (C
> @.
> \amalg
> @.
> C')
> @.
> \hspace{-0.5em}/{\sim}
> \\
> @VxVV
> @.
> @VxVV
> @.
> @VVuV
> \\
> \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})
> @.
> =
> @.
> (\mathbb{C}
> @.
> \amalg
> @.
> \mathbb{C})
> @.
> \hspace{-0.5em}/{\sim'}
> \end{CD}
> $$
>   This map $x$ is well-defined since if $a \neq 0$ then the point $(a,b)$ on the first chart is mapped to $a$ on the first chart of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$, and the corresponding point $(a^{-1}, a^{-1} b)$ is mapped to $a^{-1}$ on the second chart of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$, and these points coincide in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$.
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn9Cb.png)

What is the general theory behind this? I don't have knowledge of manifolds/complex manifolds.

Comment: $S^3/\sim\simeq \Bbb RP^3$ and not $S^2$.

Comment: @Berci you are correct, but I am talking about complex projective space. For complex projective space $\Bbb CP^n=S^{2n+1}/\sim$.

Comment: I think a real quick look at even the wikipedia page for manifolds will help here.  What is being written really is the basic idea of manifold theory.  describe a topological space as a union of open subsets that are each isomorphic to some distinguished class ( like $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Putting requirements on the isomorphism or the composition of the isomorphisms where the classes overlap gets you topological manifold theory, smooth manifold theory, complex manifold theory, etc.

Comment: @Callus thanks. Can you tell name of some book that I can refer to, where similar techniques are used for compactificaton? I would like to see more examples. This is the first time that I saw use of disjoint union and quotient to find compactificaton. I understand the discussion on charts and gluing together (like in CW complex) above but not being able to find motivation for this method (advantages).

Comment: I don't know that it's a "technique for compactification".  Finding a good compactification of a space within a certain category can be a really hard problem, in particular when we look at moduli spaces.  I don't think I know of a book that describes manifolds as a tool for compactifying.  If you want a good book to get started with manifolds, especially since it sounds like you have a topological bent, I would suggest John Lee's books.  They are modern, well written, and very suitable for early graduate or advanced undergraduate study.